# Hyper-V dynamic ram not working with Debian

Tags: debian, memory, hyper-v

I've a Windows Server 2012 R2 based Hyper-V host with Windows Server 2012 R2 guest VMs and also Debian 7.6 based VMs. The dynamic RAM is working on Windows guests fine. But on Linux its not and the VM is using the swap instead of getting more RAM from the host!

```
~#free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           490        484          5          0          1          6
-/+ buffers/cache:        476         13
Swap:         1287        106       1181
```

Some time later:

```
~# free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           490        484          5          0          1          6
-/+ buffers/cache:        476         13
Swap:         1287        110       1177
```

As you can see, the used swap increased from 106MB to 110MB and the real RAM is still on 490MB. 
In the Hyper-V settings I configured the following:

```
RAM on startup: 512MB
Minimal RAM: 512MB
Maximum RAM: 6000MB
```

I activated the kernel-modules for the Hyper-V integration tools by using http://blogs.msdn.com/b/virtual_pc_guy/archive/2010/10/21/installing-ubuntu-server-10-10-on-hyper-v.aspx
So the following kernel-modules are activated:

```
hv_vmbus
hv_storvsc
hv_netvsc
```

The output of lsmod say that hv_blkvsc isn't activated, I think that's because there is no GUI on the server.

Answer (score 4):

[According to Microsoft](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn614985.aspx), Debian does not support Hyper-V dynamic memory.

Comment: And there is nothing changed in 7.6 ? Because the Microsoft article is only for 7.0-7.4 and the modules are avaliable and activated like in Ubuntu, which is supported by Microsoft.

Comment: @user3276634 Doubtful. Debian doesn't generally add major new features to its kernels within a major release.

Comment: For anyone still looking at this answer, the article in this answer has been updated.  Debian 8.0-8.5 (jessie) still isn't supported with dynamic memory in Hyper-V, although support for some of the other integration components was added.

Comment: It _should_ become available in stretch, but I haven't personally tested it yet.

Comment: Now that Stretch is out, has anyone tested it?